# Is there a way to get the person who gave the role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot with discord.py and I want to get the person who gave the role. Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am not sure but maybe when someone got a role you can read from the Audit Log by filtering UpdateRoles to catch it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742668/12706936

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496039/12706936